# Can't bind to 'xxx' since it isn't a known property of 'tag yyy' kendo angular dropdown

Tags: angular, angular8, kendo-dropdown, kendo-angular-ui

I'm developing angular 8 app with Kendo UI.

So, I have this dropdown with custom template:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist name="theme"
                    [data]="themeItems"
                    [textField]="'text'"
                    [valueField]="'id'"
                    [(ngModel)]="theme"
                    (valueChange)="onChangeTheme($event)"
                    style="width: 100%">
    <ng-template kendoDropDownListValueTemplate let-dataItem>
        <span *ngIf="dataItem != null">
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-{{dataItem?.id}} pr-1"></i>{{ dataItem?.text }}
        </span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoDropDownListItemTemplate let-dataItem>
        <span data-toggle="theme" [data-theme]="dataItem.url">
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-{{dataItem.id}} pr-1"></i>{{ dataItem.text }}
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

And `themeItems`:

```
themeItems = [
        {
            id: 'default',
            text: 'Default',
            url: 'default'
        }, {
            id: 'amethyst',
            text: 'Amethyst',
            url: 'assets/css/themes/amethyst.min.css'
        }, {
            id: 'city',
            text: 'City',
            url: 'assets/css/themes/city.min.css'
        }
];
```

And I see error `Can't bind to 'data-theme' since it isn't a known property of 'span'`

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be
`data-theme="{{dataItem.url}}"`

no `[]` on the left but `{{}}` on the right side of the `=`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me `Can't bind to 'theme' since it isn't a known property of 'span'`.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be: `[attr.data-theme]="dataItem.url"`